# Wet indicator is red

Tags: iphone

I own an old iPhone 4s, it is known that the wifi can "stop" working. If you clear the headphone jack all the way down it will fix it but it will also make the phone think it got wet. Is there a way I can make it white again?

Comment: No, you can't reverse the indicators. Why do you want to change the moisture indicator? Are you looking to take it to Apple but don't want them to know that its been damaged by getting wet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - have the iPhone repaired and Apple will remedy the damage caused by the liquid as well as get you a device without the indicators tripped.

Beware of third party repair services since they might just open up the device and paint over the indicator and not remedy the deeper damage that the liquid has caused.